# Insert valve from listview to Sql (using linq to sql)

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, data-binding, datacontext

i have three different Listview which is Item,quantity and price. All the items for the listview will be added from a textbox. I would like to know how can i store the listview items into my SQl database. Here is the code i use to add item into the listview.

```
private void SalesAddItemBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListProductName.Items.Add(ComSalesProduct.Text);
        ListProductQuantity.Items.Add(txtSalesQuantity.Text);
        ListProductCost.Items.Add("RM " + txtSalesCost.Text+".00");
    }
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you binding your ListViews against a list of items from the database?

Comment: @GalacticCowboy..Nop..its not binding..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your entity is defined something like this:

```
 public class Order
 {
       public string product;
       public string quantity;
       public string cost;
  }
```

You can Zip to combine the lists and update the database:

```
 var orders = ListProductName.Zip(ListProductQuantity, (p, q) => new { Product = p, Quantity = q }).Zip(
            ListProductCost, (p, c) => new Order() { product = p.Product, quantity = p.Quantity, cost = c });


        db.Orders.InsertAllOnSubmit(orders);            
        db.SubmitChanges();
```