# How to insert data to sql collected inside of a listview using linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have listview on my program that consists from 3 columns; TD, AD and CT.
Data entry is made by three text boxes and one button. Every press of the button logs text box input to Listview. Listview collects 50 lines of input.

To save this data i have table is SQL named MeasVal. MeasVal has an identity key named MeasID. Every press of button should insert listview collection to sql with same identity key. My problem is i couldn't find a way to insert these data collected in the listview to sql using Linq.

Comment: Hi, can you please show what have you done so far? do you have any code? or getting any errors?

Comment: Hi Aman. I don't have code for the listview part because literally i have no idea how to do it. But i've found following thread. This thread explains how to do it from three different listviews using a zip method, but not quite what i need;https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928026/insert-valve-from-listview-to-sql-using-linq-to-sql